# Jxls 1.0 RC2 + java 8

Tags: java-8, jxls

for some reasons we still use jxls 1.0 RC2. On system with JRE 6 everything worked ok. Now on upgraded system with JRE 8 we are getting following exception:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid literal/lengths set
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:194)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource$FakeZipEntry.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:114)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:55)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:82)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:220)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:63)
at net.sf.jxls.transformer.XLSTransformer.transformXLS(XLSTransformer.java:217)
at net.sf.jxls.transformer.XLSTransformer.transformXLS(XLSTransformer.java:198)
at cgi.reportspos.ReportsPOS.export(ReportsPOS.java:374)
at cgi.reportspos.ReportsPOS.main(ReportsPOS.java:404)
```

My question is: can the JXLS 1.0 RC2 work with Java 8?

Thanks in advance for help.

Regards, Zdenek

Comment: The exception is related to Apache POI. So check the version of POI libraries you use and check if they support Java 8. Possibly you will be able just update the POI libraries in your project to a higher version supporting Java 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jXLS v1.x is compatible with Java 8. The issue was caused by corrupted xlsx templates.